# Flattening out parent/child relationship records into 1 row in SQL (Updated)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have up to 3 records on the same order number (Click the link below to see image).  I need to flatten this into 1 row because my Target table has a denormalized (flatten) schema. I would need to do this for all 3 sets – firstcolX, secondcolX, thirdcolX, so it’s just 1 row.  The 1:N relationship is order (parent) to order line items (child)

[Please click here to see desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hJ0p.jpg)

Thanks, really appreciate any help on this.  FWIW, I'm using SSIS to move data from SQL source to SQL target. I tried PIVOT, but we don’t want row data as column names.

Comment: How do you know those rows have parent-child relationship? The example data show no relation between them.

Comment: To ask differently, given the values of K0861, k0108 and 23434 in that `firstcol1a`, how do we know what the first value is? Would it be incorrect if the resultant row was 23434, k0861, k0108?

Comment: @billinkc, I've updated the image to help explain better.  But yes, to answer your question yes they would need to be in order how I tried to show in the picture.  Since we are mapping those values we need the data to be consistent

Comment: how do you decide column order ? which is first column, second column, third column.

Comment: @venkataraman R The way it would need to flatten out would be row 1 values go in the A columns (which are already there), row 2 values go in the B columns, and row 3 values go in the C columns

Comment: HOw do you know row order or does it even matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate RowNumber and then use derived table to achieve this.

```sql
;WITH CTE_TableName AS
(
SELECT *,RowNumber() over(Partition by myOrderNum ORDER BY MyOrderNum) AS rnk
FROM TableName
)
SELECT myOrderNum,firstcol1A
,(SELECT firstCol1A FROM CTE_TableName WHERE rnk =2 AND OrderNum = c.OrderNum) AS firstCol1B
,(SELECT firstCol1A FROM CTE_TableName WHERE rnk =3 AND OrderNum = c.OrderNum) AS firstCol1C
,SecondCol2A
,(SELECT SecondCol2A FROM CTE_TableName WHERE rnk =2 AND OrderNum = c.OrderNum) AS ,SecondCol2B
,(SELECT SecondCol2A FROM CTE_TableName WHERE rnk =3 AND OrderNum = c.OrderNum) AS ,SecondCol2C
,thirdCol3A
,(SELECT thirdCol3A FROM CTE_TableName WHERE rnk =2 AND OrderNum = c.OrderNum) AS thirdCol3B
,(SELECT thirdCol3A FROM CTE_TableName WHERE rnk =3 AND OrderNum = c.OrderNum) AS thirdCol3C
FROM CTE_TableName AS c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it similar to Venkataram but do the work in the join instead of correlated subqueries:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT *,RowNumber() over(Partition by myOrderNum ORDER BY MyOrderNum) AS rnk
FROM TableName
)
Select cte1.myOrderNum 
   ,cte1.FirstCol1A 
   ,cte2.FirstCol1A as FirstCol1B
   ,cte3.FirstCol1A as FirstCol1C
...
from cte cte1
    join cte cte2 on cte2.myOrderNum = cte1.myOrderNum and cte2.rnk=2
    join cte cte3 on cte3.myOrderNum = cte1.myOrderNum and cte3.rnk=3
where cte1.rnk=1
```

EDIT: Changed ordernum to MyOrderNUm

Comment: Hi @KeithL
In your example query, where are you getting the cte1.ordernum, cte2.orderNum, and cte3.orderNum fields from in your 2nd Select statement?  In my example screenshot, there is not an ordernum column (just myordernum).  When I try to plugin my field values I'm receiving an invalid columnname error

Comment: change the name to MyOrderNum